# How to handle Data Structure of size greater than 16 Mb in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am unable to compile a RPGLE program as it includes a data structure array of size greater than 16Mb.

> Compilation Error:
>
> RNF0376 - The data item is larger than the maximum of 16,773,104
>   bytes.

I know we can use pointers as workaround, is there any other solution ?

Comment: That is a big data structure. My general go-to alternative (a user space) also maxes out at 16MB). What are you trying to do that needs such a large array?

Comment: Would it make sense to create physical file in the TEMP library?  This would last only as long as the current job.

Comment: Also, ponder the difference between an array of structures vs. a structure of arrays,  The second one is easier to break apart into separate arrays.  Your total byte count will still be as high, but they would be stored as separate variables instead of one huge data structure.  Sometimes that kind of difference can keep the compiler happy.

Comment: Its actually a nested data structure array. It has two arrays and many other fields as sub fields. I am trying to return this data structure array for web service.

Comment: is it ok to use teraspace storage model for this data structure ?

Comment: You can use teraspace, but that won't change the size limit of the data structure. You might want to do a little redesign to break up the web service into smaller parts rather than a single huge web service.

Comment: Can you show the WSDL for the webservice?

Comment: Actually, It is a web service based on REST.

Answer (score 0):

Would a dynamic array solve your problem?

I'm curious, how are you returning this to a web service? Is it a SQLRPGLE program using SET RESULTS ARRAY and acting as an external stored procedure?

If so you could declare a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, fill it, and SET RESULTS CURSOR ...